# Why can't I install php7.4-intl on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, dependencies, php7

I need the INTL module for PHP on Ubuntu 20.04. When I do

```
$ sudo apt install php7.4-intl
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-intl : Depends: php7.4-common (= 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.2) but 7.4.8-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

We all know that the broken packages message is a red herring. (Yes, I checked...)

As I'm on 20.04 I'm supicious against the `ubuntu19.10.1` part of the package that `apt` suggests.

PHP says:

```
PHP 7.4.8 (cli) (built: Jul 13 2020 16:46:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.8, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

which makes me even more confused. I have tried what I can find googling to remedy any inconsistencies in the apt configuration and cache. (`dpkg --configure -a`, `apt clean/autoclean`, ...)

Comment: What if you install "php7.4-common" first and then install that package?

Comment: Why wouldn't I have `php7.4-common` when I have PHP7.4 installed? But I'll investigate...

Comment: Well, I did: `php7.4-common is already the newest version (7.4.8-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+3).`

Comment: To me it looks like the version of `php7.4-intl` for Ubuntu 20.04 is built with the wrong dependency (towards php7.4.3 instead of 7.4.8)... But that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php7.4-intl` is being installed from the Ubuntu repositories, not the `deb.sury` PPA / third party repositories you have installed and are using for your PHP.

Either don't install `php-intl` or don't use the deb.sury repos.  The use of the third party repositories is going to inhibit you from installing everything if it isn't provided in those third party repositories.

Comment: Nice catch! I ´ll just check that and the, probably, accept your answer.

Comment: I had ondrej-ubuntu-php-eoan in `/etc/apt/sources.d`. But that did not show up with `apt policy` and `ppa-purge` could not find it. An `add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ondrej/php` did something, but put `apt` in some strange state. Re-adding the deb.sury repo added the `focal` version which fixed it and at least had php-intl. I'll investigate further, but thanks for spotting the problem!